# Is it fine to power a buzzer that requires only 3V using the 3V3 pin of the Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: gpio, voltage

I have a solid state relay but I think I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Do you  mean from the 3.3v supply pin or a GPIO? Also, what's the current drawn by the buzzer?

Comment: I am a little bit confused.  Did you use the relay to drive the buffer. And there are two types of buzzer. Piezo buzzer usually use a transistor. Electromagnet buzzers usually is directly driver by 3/5/11/24V. I sometimes directly use a GPIO pin to drive a 5/12V buzzer. I usually first use a DMM to check the current and almost find 3 to 5mA. I sometime use GPIO to drive 2N2222 or 2N7000 which in turn drives the buzzer.  Active piezo buzzer are usually 5V powered, but Rpi GPIO might have a problem driving the transistor. Electromagnet buzzers can usually direct driven by Rpi GPIO.

Comment: But there is a RISK of back EMF frying the GPIO pin. But the risk is very very small, because the energy stored in the coil is not big enough to fry the GPIO circuit. The back EMF spike is usually 10~15V.  I know it is a bit confusing.  If you wish to dig down and see the 15V spike etc, you can read the following posts.  Please feel free to ask me to clarify anything: (1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&hilit=buzzer+tlfong01&start=50#p1402122,
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&p=1407253&hilit=buzzer+tlfong01#p1407253,

Comment: (3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97980/active-piezo-buzzer-makes-sound-on-both-rpi-gpio-low-and-high-level-signal,
(4) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104573/piezo-buzzer-driven-by-rpi-gpio-problem,
(5) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103868/piezo-sensor-to-pick-up-acoustic-instrument-signal-using-rpi-and-adc.

Comment: I have no idea what current the buzzer draws. It was just handed to me with no specifications about it. I tested it with one 1.5V AAA battery and it sounded so weak but when I used two 1.5V AAA it was loud.

Comment: Ah, yes, if your buzzer is 3V, 5V, or 12V, then 1.5V usually not strong enough to make a big enough sound. I would test with 2 AAA 1.5V x 2 = 3V. The buzzer should make a louder sound.  Now What is important is to use the multimeter to measure  the current. As I said, if it is 3 ~ 5 mA, then you can take the risk 0.05% to fry the GPIO pin.  Of course the safest is to use a trasnsitor to drive it.  But if you skim my post and let me know if yours is rectangular, box like, or black round button, the I can give a more sensible suggestion. BTW, using 2 AAA batteries to do testing is a good idea :)